# Java Keylogger for Java phones

Tags: mobile, java-me

I've looked all around in google, there are many key loggers for any phones OS except java, with a simple search you can find hundreds of SMS key loggers and Spy apps for Android, Symbian, Windows Mobile, etc... but there is not any for Java phones!

While it was getting wired for me, I asked a J2ME programmer, he said it's not possible to have an application running in background for java phones, or not possible to hide applications! is that right? I'm web developer and have no idea about J2ME/Java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all the mobile keylogger software can only be used for Smartphones, I am not sure if there is any software for java.

Comment: but why? is there any chance to make it or not at all?